# A spreadsheet sort of object on a webpage

Tags: javascript, html, dhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Spreadsheet-like control for a web application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/204310/spreadsheet-like-control-for-a-web-application)

So I'm not sure what sort of tools are available, and so I don't actually know how I might go about implementing what I want.

Currently, I have a webpage that parses information that the user provides using javascript. Basically, there's a textarea and users just copy-paste formatted text based on my specifications and in another textarea it will display a nice formatted output based on the input given.

The input is structured like a table: an arbitrary number of columns with headers and arbitrary number of rows representing unique items. The columns are tab-separated so when I parse each item, I split on tabs and then iterate over each field.

Because of this, if a field is empty, you must still have a tab so the data lines up properly.
I decided to use tabs because our data could contain all sorts of characters including spaces, commas, periods, etc. so tabs seemed like a pretty good option.

I've also found that a spreadsheet is the easiest to work with, where people can just format their input on excel and then copy-paste it as tab-separated values onto my webpage. This has reduced the amount of time required to get the job done by ten-fold and they really like it.

One comment was that I should provide a way to allow people to directly format their input on the webpage itself so they don't have to switch between windows or open excel, but I said I don't know if there are ways to do that.

Is there a way to get a spreadsheet-type of object onto a webpage where I can parse it with javascript?

Comment: Are you using any frameworks like jQuery? What you want is usually called a grid. [ExtJS](http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/examples/grid/edit-grid.html) is particularly good for this in my opinion but there is a commercial license fee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this in action in the Rico grids ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rico_(Ajax) ) which allow you to view the grid as a spreadsheet. export-owc.html has an spreadsheet object embedded in the webpage, and the contents of which is filled out by javascript.
Microsoft site on spread sheet object:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa205671(v=office.11).aspx
I think you can use all the listed properties and methods on the object -- for example the Rico file mentioned has following lines where 'ss' is the id of the spreadsheet object.

```
 var oSS=document.getElementById('ss')
  if (!oSS) {
    alert('Error! Can not find spreadsheet');
    return;
  }
  oSS.HTMLData=oDiv.innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Sencha/EXT](http://www.sencha.com/products/extjs/examples/) framework has data grid capabilities.

Answer (score 1):

Try [SlickGrid](https://github.com/mleibman/SlickGrid/wiki) - it's what we use on [dirigible](http://www.projectdirigible.com) - v flexible spreadsheet/grid component, can be read-only or editable.  I'd keep the textarea for ppl to cut & paste raw text into, you should then be able to parse it and populate the slickgrid elsewhere on the page, which users can then edit if they need to.