# Excel Sheet in web page ? Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

In web application, can we display the excel sheet in web page [asp.net web page], is they any way to display rather tahn grid view, i tried in gridview but it is not displaying in a good format, can you please sujest me, how to display the excel sheet in web page.

Answer (score 0):

> i tried in gridview but it is not displaying in a good format

You should have to learn and experience the power of cascade style sheet.

You may use `DataList`, `ListView`, `Repeator` or you may construct your own control to display data on web-page.

Comment: Mr AVD, format in the sense , columns data is mismatching with actualy excel data.

Comment: this is my previous question, where i place screent schot, please go through this question. Excel Data to gridview ? In Asp.net?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an ASP.NET control which works similar to Excel then try using these answers.

- [Excel like server side control for ASP.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58289/excel-like-server-side-control-for-asp-net)
- http://www.componentart.com